# Redis command to test a Celery work

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery

I'm experimenting with a Celery worker using Redis as broker.

This is my test code for the Celery worker:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://xxxxx.net:6379/0')

@app.task
def nextexec(payload):
    print(payload)
```

Using the `redis-cli`, I am running the following command to insert a value into the `celery` queue (created automatically by Celery)

```
RPUSH celery somekey 'somevalue'
```

But my worker systematically crashes when the query is executed, I get an `Unrecoverable error: JSONDecodeError`. It seems to receive `None` instead of supposedly a JSON string to decode.

Any idea what Redis query I need to execute or what changes I need to bring to this (yet simple) worker script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery uses [serializers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#serializers) to transfer data between clients and workers. Every message needs to be serialized and has a content_type header that describes the serialization method used to encode it.

Here is a sample message which is serialized using json.

```
{'body': 'W1sxXSwge30sIHsiY2FsbGJhY2tzIjogbnVsbCwgImVycmJhY2tzIjogbnVsbCwgImNoYWluIjogbnVsbCwgImNob3JkIjogbnVsbH1d',
 'content-encoding': 'utf-8',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'headers': {'argsrepr': '(1,)',
  'eta': None,
  'expires': None,
  'group': None,
  'id': '5ce9a8d8-41d7-47a4-9074-beedabd88dcc',
  'kwargsrepr': '{}',
  'lang': 'py',
  'origin': 'gen5339@pavilion',
  'parent_id': None,
  'retries': 0,
  'root_id': '5ce9a8d8-41d7-47a4-9074-beedabd88dcc',
  'task': 't.wait',
  'timelimit': [None, None]},
 'properties': {'body_encoding': 'base64',
  'correlation_id': '5ce9a8d8-41d7-47a4-9074-beedabd88dcc',
  'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'},
  'delivery_mode': 2,
  'delivery_tag': '0177eb65-344e-4b1c-ab5f-8e2f5d75b8d3',
  'priority': 0,
  'reply_to': 'a5c611b8-18b3-3bbb-b598-c3757f06c4fd'}}
```

Celery workers need to receive message in a specified format. You can't push some value to broker(redis) and expect celery to execute it.

Use python to queue up your tasks.

```
from mymodule import nextexec
payload ='some payload'
nextexec.delay(payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was the kind of info I was looking for and it was not clear from reading the celery docs and tutorials.